# Question Regarding the Format of Multiplying with Trig Functions

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

There is a question that I am asked in my math book which states:

> Why was $a$sin $B$ used instead of sin$B \cdot a$?

I am not sure why there is this difference. I would greatly appreciate it if someone can explain why its better to use the previous choice rather than the latter one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same, but the first is better.

I think because if we'll write $\sin B\cdot a$ then there is a probability for  calculation  $\sin(Ba)$.

Otherwise, if we'll write $a\sin{B}$ then this possibility is less.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!